# usb_claim_interface() on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hid

I'm trying to get a USB HID device to work on Raspberry Pi.

The code utilizes the [RawHID](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/rawhid.html) lib for MacOSX/Linux/Windows.

I got it working on MacOSX, but for other reasons I can't use it on that OS anymore. Now I'm trying to get it to work on Raspberry Pi via `hid_LINUX.c`.

When I tried it out, it just completely fails to connect. I added the debug info, and found out it's failing here:

```
if (usb_claim_interface(u, i) < 0) {          
    printf("  unable claim interface %d\n", i); 
    continue;                                   
}
```

I tried googling for ages and I see various things about...

- modprobe.d blacklist (didn't work, although that looked for for rtl devices... not sure)
- updating all packages (didn't work)
- compiling your own version of `libhid` (I don't know why I'd have to do this, considering the creator of the USB device recommended this RawHID lib which uses `libusb-dev` (`usb.h`), and which works fine on OS X and Windows)

Does anyone have any possible ideas how I can proceed? How do I 'free' my USB device so I can claim it?

I have a Raspberry Pi B+

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. I'm trying to read temperature sensors with my RPi. Could solve this problem?

Comment: I solved it but it was years ago so I have no idea what I did :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I solved it by just running the code with `sudo` rights ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can not comment (insufficient reputation) so I answer instead:
I finally found the reason for my problem with the comment "Now I solved it by just running the code with sudo rights" above, so I'm grateful!

I use a Pi 3b for Domoticz for > 3 years. (same software on PC before that) After a failed update, followed by a complete re-install, my CM15 Domoticz interface (connected via USB) would be recognized as present with lsusb, but would not work. I boot my PI from a USB key, so maybe the -very old- USB key failed, so I bought a new USB 3.0 key. No joy. USB 3.0 uses more power, maybe draining USB power from my CM15, so I bought a bigger supply. Did not solve the problem.So I bought a new memory card, no change.
Searching for "usb_claim_interface failed -6 mochad" brought me here for a correct diagnostic and the way to make it work "manually"
Not yet the solution; normally libusb starts the "interface" software (mochad) when it finds a new USB device connected, but "claiming it" apparently now requires more permissions. Now that I understand the problem, I'll find the answer.
Thanks much for showing the way dennis-tra!